# How can I calculate the population size of a collectible from the number of them sold? Best way to quantify rarity?

Tags: sample-size, population

I'm writing a book on the rarity of antique bottles from a certain state. I want to be able to rigorously define the rarity of a given variant through an estimation of population sizes for that given variant. This is something that people in the community haven't done yet but would be a boon to the stability of prices and historical understanding of the individual manufacturers and their communities.

I'm thinking that a good estimate for the rarity of a particular bottle is the proportion of the total population (i.e., the sum of of all variant populations), then normalized and multiplied by 5 for a scale of rarity from 1 to 5. The issue is in estimating the population sizes from the number of observed sales of the bottles. Moreover, not every variant that exists has been sold at some point. As an example, consider Eckman Bottling Works. They have four known variants:

1. Amber Coca-Cola, "Eckman Bottling Works" embossed on the front, ECK1 (call this $n_1$)
2. Amber Coca-Cola, "Coca-Cola" on front and "Eckman, W.Va." on back, ECK2 ($n_2$)
3. Amber Coca-Cola, "Coca-Cola" on front, "Eckman, W.Va." on back, "C.W.E." on bottom, ECK3 ($n_3$)
4. Aqua unbranded, "Eckman Bottling Works / Eckman, W.Va." on the front, ECK4 ($n_4$)

Now, ECK1 and ECK2 have sales records on worthpoint, with 1 sold each. For the number sold, I will denote them as $s_i$, so $s_1 = 1$ and $s_2 = 1$. ECK3 and ECK4 have not been sold online. Only an image of ECK4 exists. A census I took among collectors pinned the populations of $n_1$ = 3, $n_2 =$ 4, $n_3 =$ 1, and $n_4$ is assumed to be 1.

From this, for my first book, I simply assumed that the total population of a variant was $n_i = 3.5s_i$ if $s \geq 1$. I then just used the raw number of examples for a variant to quantify rarity. For example, if I estimated $1 \leq n_1 \leq 5$, then I would say it has a rarity of 5. If $6 \leq n_2 \leq 10$, then I would say that variant has a rarity of 4. And so on, with 1 being 20+ examples. But this doesn't take the greater context of the total population of bottles into account and it's based on very rough estimations. A glaring assumption that was often violated is that sometimes these bottles just aren't sold online, even if they may be very common.

So, all of that said I have asked other statisticians online and in my PhD program what their opinion is and the best suggestion was to build a model based on the final sale price of the individual examples of variants sold online.

The issue with this is that the market does fluctuate for these bottles and they are subject to different demands. So, the Eckman Coca-Cola bottles would fetch greater prices than ECK4, just by virtue of having national demand. Milk bottles with War Bonds advertisements on them fetch more than others due to greater historical interest. If I went this route, I guess I could always just categorize them based on these different attributes (e.g., the Eckman Coca-Cola bottles are modeled separately from ECK4 due to higher sale prices). Another issue is that condition matters a great deal, so the same variant's sale price can vary significantly on those grounds.

All of that being considered, I'm at a loss. It seems that I can't build this model without at least knowing the population of several variants and extrapolating that. But this is a hobby overwhelmingly made up of older folks, many of whom do not use the internet period. That's along with the many people who might have one and not be a part of the hobby. I'm not concerned about the possibility of many still being in the ground or in a barn somewhere, as those (for my purposes) don't yet exist.

Finally, here are two important points on the manufacturing of these bottles, since someone suggested something similar to the German tank problem or tag-and-release method:

1. There were an incredible number of manufacturers for these bottles.

   - Records of bottlers (e.g., Eckman Bottling Works) ordering bottles from manufacturers (e.g., D.O.C. glassworks) just don't really exist anymore.
   - Records that do exist do not speak to how many examples survived for collectors today.

     - E.g., they do not account for how many bottles have been destroyed, lost, or returned.
2. Variants almost always have different manufacturer codes embossed on their glass than the other variants under a given bottler.

   - E.g., ECK1 might have "D.O.C. 1234" while ECK2 might have "C.B.Co. 4321"

     - These are not unique to the bottle, but instead unique to the variant. Each example of a variant will have the same manufacturer code.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions and ideas or need more information about the bottles. Creating a quantitative way of determining how many bottles survived from a bottler and city would be incredibly informative to consumption and sanitation practices, the success of a bottler, and more.

Comment: I haven't read your question carefully enough to really get the idea, but maybe there are some methods from population ecology, which has a whole branch devoted to estimating population sizes from weird/sparse observational data?